# How to use dynamic global list in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter and attempting sample mutual fund app to cover all basic widgets.

**Requirement** -> After selecting MF scheme, when user confirms on "buyNow" screen, corresponding scheme should get added to global dynamic list in "Cart" screen. This is basically a cart which is accessible to user on any screen, similar to shopping cart. I want to update cart list on "buyNow" screen and display same on "Cart" screen.

I have followed [link](https://github.com/flutter/samples/blob/master/provider_shopper/lib/main.dart) to learn about 'provider' method of flutter to solve this, but not able to do.

PFB code

**Main.dart**

```html
void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => CartModel(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Schemelist(),
        routes: {
          '/landing': (context) => Landing(),
          '/schemelist': (context) => Schemelist(),
          '/schemeBuy': (context) => SchemeBuy(),
          '/buyNow': (context) => BuyNow(),
          '/cart': (context) => Cart(),
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

**Cartmodel.dart**

```html
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class CartModel with ChangeNotifier{
  String schemeName;
  String type;
  String fromDate;
  String toDate;
  double amount;
  List<CartModel> _cartList=[];
  CartModel({this.amount,this.fromDate,this.schemeName,this.toDate,this.type});

  void addToCart(CartModel cartObj){
        _cartList.add(cartObj);
        notifyListeners();
  }

  double get totalAmount =>
      _cartList.fold(0, (total, current) => total + current.amount);
}
```

**BuyNow.dart**

```html
 RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _cart=new CartModel(amount:1000,fromDate:_dateTime.toString(),schemeName:widget.investmentObj.schemeName,toDate:_dateTime1.toString(),type:'SIP');
             var cart = Provider.of<CartModel>(context);
             cart.addToCart(_cart);
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/cart');
          },
          child: Text('Yes'),
        ),
```

**Cart.dart**   //where I will display dynamic list

```html
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var cart = Provider.of<CartModel>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Cart'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: --not able to access list--
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
          title: Text(
            -------
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: what error or issue you are facing?

Comment: In Cart screen, I am not finding way to populate listview builder with this dynamic global list?

Comment: You aren't showing an error in your code or explaining your problem. You seem to have some sort of Provider sharing data across your app and it seems to be accessible on your card.dart file, so what is the problem?

Comment: can you please elaborate what you want to achieve?

Comment: @All thank you for revert. I am not getting any error on console as am step back from implementing functionality. Problem is I do not know how to add object(from buyNow screen) to global cart list(to be populated on Cart screen) dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we should modify CartModel class. The fields (such as schemeName) should belong to the CartItem class, and the CartModel should only do its own thing (addToCart and others).

```
class CartModel with ChangeNotifier {
  List<CartItem> _itemList = [];

  // An unmodifiable view of the items in the cart.
  UnmodifiableListView<CartItem> get itemList => UnmodifiableListView(_itemList);

  void addToCart(CartItem item) {
    _itemList.add(item);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  double get totalAmount => _itemList.fold(0, (total, current) => total + current.amount);
}

class CartItem{
  String schemeName;
  String type;
  String fromDate;
  String toDate;
  double amount;

  CartItem({this.amount, this.fromDate, this.schemeName, this.toDate, this.type});
}
```

Then, in Cart.dart

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var itemList = Provider.of<CartModel>(context).itemList;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Cart'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: itemList.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
          var item = itemList[index];
          return Text(item.schemeName);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

You will get a error while click RaisedButton:

```
Tried to listen to a value exposed with provider, from outside of the widget tree.

This is likely caused by an event handler (like a button's onPressed) that called
Provider.of without passing `listen: false`.
```

To fix it, edit BuyNow.dart:

```
RaisedButton(
 onPressed: () {
   var _item = CartItem(amount: 1000, fromDate: _dateTime.toString(), schemeName: widget.investmentObj.schemeName, toDate: _dateTime1.toString(), type: 'SIP');
   //just set listen to false
   var cart = Provider.of<CartModel>(context, listen: false);
   cart.addToCart(_item);
   Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/cart');
 },
 child: Text('Yes'),
),
```

Comment: Thank you for quick revert. It is working now. I will add cart action button appbar and will try to access this list from any page.